# Gratis bulk email sender software to use on Windows 7?

Tags: windows, gratis, email, office, spam

I have created a mailing list in `Microsoft Access 2010` that contains about 3000 emails in the following format:

[image]

As you see these are researchers from all over the world with **different mail servers** because of the different institutes and universities they work in. (I want to invite them to a special occasion)
I want to create a special gmail account for this task or use my university email that is like `someone@ut.ac.ir` and send them a short email like this **just one time for each**

> Dear sir or madam
>   a pre written text

Is there any open source or free software that can be installed on a Windows 7 x64 laptop and do this tedious job of email sending for me with the following conditions?

- The email should be sent just one time to each person without any
  mistake (They may block me if the program makes mistakes)
- The email should go right into the inbox of the recipient and not
  into the spam folder

Up to know, I've found [this](http://bulkmailerpro.com/), but I don't know if it has all the features that I need.

---

**Edit:**
I prefer to change the email content as follows:

> Dear firstname + lastname
>
> pre written text
>
> my signature as a student of university of Tehran

Comment: While this question is off-topic here (and shall be flagged as such) I can suggest you look into a mail-merge program or plug-in for a program such as Outlook or Thunderbird.

Comment: @Tom what does gratis mean?

Comment: @sepideh Software free of financial cost. For software that includes the source code, [open-source] is the best tag. Software can be either [gratis] or [open-source], or both. - So gratis should be what your looking for, right?

Comment: BTW: you don't need a tool, you can [do it from Access itself](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa167323%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

Comment: @ThomasWeller I will fix it now

Comment: The trouble with free of charge is that you takes your money, you makes your choice. Sending bulk email 'improperly' can get you in all sorts of problems. Imagine using your own universities mail server to bulk email, and one of the recipient institutions employed a blacklist whose heuristics determined that the sending mail server (yours) is emitting spam - you run a very high risk of getting your whole universities email blacklisted. That means any email coming from your uni to that institution will get bounced. 3000 recipients sent from Campaign Monitor will cost you $35.

Comment: Just a warning - you may be breaking EU law mailing anyone in the European Union without their permission.  Have you tried mailchimp.com

Comment: Are you aware that you only failed at obscuring emails and that name/surname are visible? And that publishing this image without agreement from this people is against law in a significant parts of the world?

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous tools that can do the task of sending the mails from your list including Access or Python.

The one thing that **none** of them can do is straight to the recipients inbox as that is a rule on their side - if you or the account that you use to send the mail are already in their spam list your mail will be filtered.

The other thing to watch out for is that a lot of spam detection emails look for certain key words and for multiple identical emails so I would suggest avoiding `Dear Sir/Madam` on both counts - *not to mention that a lot of people hit delete on reading that line*.

Comment: They don't know my email to place it in the spam list already and I will send each one just one email in order to not bother them. Also my account is not a commercial one. It's an account of the University of Tehran mail server like `someone@ut.ac.ir` or a personal gmail account. ( preferably a personal gmail account ) Also if it's possible, I prefer to change the text as follows `Dear firstname+lastname......pre written text` as I have mentioned in the edit part of my original post

Comment: Do you have any solution?

Comment: @sepideh Yes - use python or access to generate personalised emails and send them and hope that the account is not on anybodies blacklist.

Comment: Making personalized emails with access will take a lot of time. What do you mean by personalized? Do you mean they should not even have the same body of text

Comment: You can use some of the fields from the DB records to personalise to a limited extent, Dear {Title} {Surname}, We at My Institute would like to request that you, or your nominated representative from {Institute}, attend .... {FirstName} I hope you will be able to attend as we are sure that this will be of interest in your work in {speciality}

Comment: And can I use access with a gmail or a ut (university of Tehran) account without using the app outlook? because I cannot figure out how to use outlook

Comment: Can I use outlook with my gmail account?

Comment: "I will send each one just one email in order to not bother them" - it is still likely to bother them and end in spam for others. Fortunately it is enough that many of spam targets will mark as spam to blacklist it for others.